# Text turned to undefined

Tags: javascript, html

whats wrong with my code?The result shows DemoUser as undefined.heres what have i done

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
Name : <span id="pname">DemoUser</span><button type="button" onclick="setname()">Edit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var nme;

document.getElementById("pname").innerHTML=nme;
function setname(){
nme = prompt("Enter your name","");
if (nme != "" && nme != ""){
setCookie("player",nme,300);
} 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `nme` doesn't have a value when you assign it to `innerHTML`. What else do you expect?

Comment: `if (nme != "" && nme != "")`? So nice you check it twice?

Comment: haha im sorry..im really doesnt realise that..really haha :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to make assign it after you get the value. Also, you're not initializing the variable, which is why it returns `undefined` also the `if` condition can be simplified a bit.

```
function setname() {
    var nme = prompt("Enter your name", "");
    if (nme) { 
        document.getElementById("pname").innerHTML = nme;
        setCookie("player", nme, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better approach